# How do I bring add the Total Price to the final output?

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a "PizzaOrder" application in with JavaFX. I've got the window up and running, and buttons, radiobuttons, dropdown menus, and checkboxes to work but can't figure out how to bring up the final price with tax included.

I am a first year college student trying to pursue coding. I have tried multiple methods but nothing has worked thus far so the code below is empty/unfinished.

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class PizzaOrderApp extends Application {

    private TextArea output;
    private Button order;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox;
    private ToggleGroup group;
    private TextField name;
    ArrayList<CheckBox> listCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Text text = new Text();

        text.setFont(Font.font("nfl minnesota vikings", FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 100));
        text.setFill(Color.DARKVIOLET);
        text.setStrokeWidth(4);
        text.setStroke(Color.GOLD);
        text.setText("SKOL PIZZA!");

        FlowPane paneTop = new FlowPane(text);
        paneTop.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        paneTop.setHgap(20);
        paneTop.setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple;");

        String crustType[] = {"Thick", "Thin", "Gluten Free" };

        choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<String>(); 
        choiceBox.getItems().addAll(crustType);
        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        VBox verticalBoxLeft = new VBox();
        verticalBoxLeft.getChildren().add(choiceBox);

        group = new ToggleGroup();

        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("10\" Pizza");
        rb1.setToggleGroup(group);
        rb1.setSelected(true);

        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("12\" Pizza");
        rb2.setToggleGroup(group);

        RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton("14\" Pizza");
        rb3.setToggleGroup(group);

        RadioButton rb4 = new RadioButton("16\" Pizza");
        rb4.setToggleGroup(group);

        verticalBoxLeft.getChildren().add(rb1);
        verticalBoxLeft.getChildren().add(rb2);
        verticalBoxLeft.getChildren().add(rb3);
        verticalBoxLeft.getChildren().add(rb4);

        verticalBoxLeft.setSpacing(10);

        Pane paneLeft = new Pane(verticalBoxLeft);
        paneLeft.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gold;");
        paneLeft.setPrefSize(200, 600);

        output = new TextArea(); 
        output.setPrefColumnCount(30);
        output.setPrefRowCount(40);
        output.setEditable(false); 
        output.setText("Order");

        Pane paneRight = new Pane(output);
        paneRight.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gold;");
        paneRight.setPrefSize(200, 600);

        Font font = new Font(18);
        Label nameLabel = new Label("Name: ");
        nameLabel.setFont(font);

        name = new TextField();
       //name.setFont(font);
        name.setPrefWidth(50);
        name.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);



        FlowPane paneCenter = new FlowPane(nameLabel, name);
        paneCenter.setHgap(20);
        paneCenter.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        CheckBox topping1 = new CheckBox("Pepperoni");
        CheckBox topping2 = new CheckBox("Sausage");
        CheckBox topping3 = new CheckBox("Chicken");
        CheckBox topping4 = new CheckBox("Bacon");
        CheckBox topping5 = new CheckBox("Pineapple");

        listCheckBoxes.add(topping1);
        listCheckBoxes.add(topping2);
        listCheckBoxes.add(topping3);
        listCheckBoxes.add(topping4);
        listCheckBoxes.add(topping5);


        paneCenter.getChildren().add(topping1);
        paneCenter.getChildren().add(topping2);
        paneCenter.getChildren().add(topping3);
        paneCenter.getChildren().add(topping4);
        paneCenter.getChildren().add(topping5);
        paneCenter.setVgap(10);

        paneCenter.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gold;");

        order = new Button("Order");
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");


        order.setOnAction(this::processButtonPress);
        cancel.setOnAction(this::processButtonPress);


        FlowPane paneBottom = new FlowPane(order, cancel);

        paneBottom.setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple;");
        paneBottom.setPrefSize(400,100);
        paneBottom.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        paneBottom.setHgap(50);


        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(paneTop);
        borderPane.setLeft(paneLeft);
        borderPane.setCenter(paneCenter);
        borderPane.setRight(paneRight);     
        borderPane.setBottom(paneBottom);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,600,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource() == order) {
            output.appendText("\nOrder Button Pushed");
            String outputText = "";
            RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) group.getSelectedToggle();
            outputText += "\nSize: "+selected.getText();
            outputText += "\nCrust: "+choiceBox.getValue();
            outputText += "\nName: "+name.getText();




            for(CheckBox element : listCheckBoxes)
                if(element.isSelected())
                    outputText += "\nTopping: "+element.getText();

            output.setText(outputText);

    }
        else {
            output.appendText("\nCancel Button Pushed");

        }
    }

    public class PizzaOrder {

        private int size;
        private String crustType;
        private String name;
        //private double topping;
        ArrayList<String> toppings = new ArrayList<String>();


        public PizzaOrder(int size, String crustType, String name)
        {
            this.size = size;
            this.crustType = crustType;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void addTopping(String topping)
        {


        }

        private double calculatePrice()
        {
            double price = 0;
            double totalPrice=0;
            double tax = .055;
            totalPrice = price + (price*tax);
            return totalPrice;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String str = toString()+ "Size: "+size+"\nCrust: "+crustType+"\nToppings: "+toppings+"\nName: "+name+"\nTax: "+(price*tax)+"\nFinal Price: "+totalPrice;
            return str;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

After selecting what the user wants, I need the final output to display:

- Size
- Crust
- Toppings
- Name
- Tax
- Final Price

Assignment Instructions:
[image]

Comment: Regarding your code formatting in markdown here, the backticks are for code in-line with other text, such as within a sentence within a paragraph. For longer blocks of code, indent with four spaces to trigger formatting. No need to combine backticks with indenting. To indent, use a text editor. Many will indent multiple selected lines of text when you press Tab key or choose a menu item for indenting.

Comment: Could you explain where exactly you're stuck? What about showing the final price with tax included is giving you trouble?

Comment: For `addToppings` method it's simply `toppings.add(topping);`  In the `toString` method, you need to loop through the toppings List and format the string correctly. I would use a `StringBuilder` to do that. The way you currently do will also work.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> can't figure out how to bring up the final price with tax included.

You are not using `PizzaOrder` at all as you were instructed. When you handle `order.setOnAction`, you should create an instance of this class and add all the toppings to it with `addTopping(String)`.

You should also implement the `calculatePrice()` method such that it uses the class's fields to calculate the price. The simplest way would be to `switch` over the `size` and set `price` based on that, then add the price for toppings based on `toppigns.size()`.

Then use the `toString()` of that instance in the `output` text area. Don't read the values from the controls.

Notes:

- Instead of

  ```
  ArrayList<CheckBox> list = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
  ```

  do

  ```
  List<CheckBox> listCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
  ```

  It's better to code to an interface in this case, and you don't need the generic type on the right side since the compiler infers that.
- Use a separate method for each button action. Don't use the same method, check the source and act based on that.